# Adobe Volume License for Indesign Digital Download Location?

Tags: licensing, adobe

We recently purchased a volume license for Adobe Indesign from Dell. We received an e-mail for the order that contains the serial #. However, there is no information on how to obtain Adobe Indesign from the Adobe licensing portal.

This is our first time dealing with Adobe volume licensing so I'm a bit lost as to what we're suppose to do. I've googled around a little and found an Adobe License Portal but I do not have access to it. Does anyone with experience concerning Adobe volume licensing have any idea what we're suppose to do to get a download of our purchase?

Comment: Have you asked Dell Support?

Comment: Or Adobe? or Superuser.com? Apart from bread-making tips I'm struggling to think of something less serverfault related

Comment: I know this isn't strictly server related but I imagine license management is something a lot of IT people deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have gotten a download link with your serial number.  You'll have to contact dell.  Note that dell is notorious for enrolling you in the "wrong" licensing scheme, no matter what the vendor which is probably why you didn't get a download link

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I didn't realize the problem was on Dell's end since this is our first time dealing with volume license purchasing.

Comment: That was it. We were suppose to get an enrollment e-mail of some sort but never got it.